How to get fully qualified section numbers in crossrefs
Inside a subsubsection I use a \ref{lll} to a another section that has \label{lll}.
If the subsubsection is in a different section than the label I get a fully qualified ref like [1.2.3].
But if in subsubsection 1 I have a ref to subsubsection 3 of the same subsubsection I get only [3]
I tried changing refs to crefs along with hyperref and cleveref packages. That resulted in the number being preceded by the word "Section" but the full qualification still is not coming.
Added Later
Evidently my analysis was wrong.
Sometimes it just points to the wrong section.
This is not related to whether it's another tree or sibling.
The following shows the details
The detailed exhibits
Note the cref link inside the section "if expression vs if statement"
The org mode file
#+LATEX_CLASS: IEEEtran
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [conference,a4paper]
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil author:nil
#+TITLE: A Title
* Aspects and Artifacts
Systemic Issues
[[*Systemic Issues]]
** Small and sundry
*** How do beginners see a comma
except clauses,  [[*Type checking]]
*** Ambiguous keywords
See ahead [[*procedure vs function]]
*** ~if else~ statement vs ~if else~ expression
discussed in section
[[*Conserve keywords]]. What is an overuse of syntax.
** Types
*** procedure vs function
*** Type checking

*** Data Structure vs Storage Structure
Our Suggestions [[*Our Suggestions]] below.
** Is ~is~ "is"?
** Systemic Issues
*** Versionitis
**** Conserve keywords
different? The syntax suggests not; the ontology however is different.
**** 2 \rightarrow 3 becomes less noob friendly
* Our Suggestions
* Bookkeeping :noexport:
:PROPERTIES:
:VISIBILITY: folded  
:END:
# Local Variables:
# org-latex-hyperref-template: nil
# org-latex-default-packages-alist: nil
# End:

The generated latex
% Created 2024-05-29 Wed 15:03
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\date{\today}
\title{A Title}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Anonymous},
 pdftitle={A Title},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Anonymous}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Aspects and Artifacts}
\label{sec:org7b3d162}
Systemic Issues
\ref{sec:orgef81a66}
\subsection{Small and sundry}
\label{sec:orgaa2c64c}
\subsubsection{How do beginners see a comma}
\label{sec:org819aa5c}
except clauses,  \ref{sec:orgb182a66}
\subsubsection{Ambiguous keywords}
\label{sec:orge3d061e}
See ahead \ref{sec:org45f719f}
\subsubsection{\texttt{if else} statement vs \texttt{if else} expression}
\label{sec:org8e7ced6}
discussed in section
\ref{sec:orgddf6c22}. What is an overuse of syntax.
\subsection{Types}
\label{sec:org39c83b9}
\subsubsection{procedure vs function}
\label{sec:org45f719f}
\subsubsection{Type checking}
\label{sec:orgb182a66}

\subsubsection{Data Structure vs Storage Structure}
\label{sec:org508c967}
Our Suggestions \ref{sec:org7f3bf5b} below.
\subsection{Is \texttt{is} "is"?}
\label{sec:org61ac8ac}
\subsection{Systemic Issues}
\label{sec:orgef81a66}
\subsubsection{Versionitis}
\label{sec:org2c4c66e}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Conserve keywords
\label{sec:orgddf6c22}
different? The syntax suggests not; the ontology however is different.
\item 2 \(\rightarrow\) 3 becomes less noob friendly
\label{sec:org4978ffc}
\end{enumerate}
\section{Our Suggestions}
\label{sec:org7f3bf5b}
\end{document}

The latex generated pdf

Also for reference the libreoffice which has the correct fully qualified section


Please can you provide code for an example we can compile. but I expect that makes little difference then I'm afraid your expectations will not be fulfilled. The default behaviour of LaTeX is to provide a fully qualified cross-reference, even if the reference is to the current subsubsection or whatever. You can try the experiment safely at home.

@cfr My tex file is 700 lines long. Not to mention bib, sty files. It will take me a a few hours to cut it down to a MWE

"But if in subsubsection 1 I have a ref to subsubsection 3 of the same subsubsection I get only [3]" that isn't standard behaviour so unless you show an example that does that it may be hard to tell you what to change, since you are asking for the standard behaviour.

@Rusi it should only take you a few minutes not hours to make an example. just make a \label and \ref  to a subsection on the first page, delete everything after the first subsection (so you do not need bib files) check the problem shows, then delete all packages that are not needed in the example, and post the resulting document in your question.

O I think I see my error now! Latex doesnt have subsubsubsection !¡!¡! Sorry for the noise. I guess I have to destructure my document?

the command for the 4th level section heading is \paragraph

I guess it was not a Latex question but an org mode setting.
After 3 stars (***) org mode by default stops exporting as headings but as lists.
This default can be changed.  Putting this line in the org file
#+OPTIONS: H:4
or setting org-export-headline-level to 4 in the emacs setup makes it work (it seems!)
